# Как получить из строки последнее слово?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Пример строки `Пример пример №1 300986190`. Как получить только последние цифры? Нужно получить только последние цифры даже если будет такая срока `Пример пример №2 1 2 3 4 5 6 6666666`.

Использую строку вот так `String Tekst2 = "set UNP=" + ObyektProgramm2;`, где `ObyektProgramm2` наша строка.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Последнее слово из цифр, 6666666

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Последнее слово это УНП, нужно считать его независимо от того что стоит впереди

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Есть одно точная примета, цифр - 9. Хотелось бы искать не по пробелу или запятой а независимо от того что будет написано впереди вообще. Может есть простой способ считать 9 последних цифр всего одной строкой?

Comment: @Ele, у вас во втором примере цифр не девять

Comment: @mymedia Не важно, вопрос был в том как получить последние цифры а не 9 последних. 9 цифр я написал к тому что-бы возможно облегчить решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярное выражения для извлечения цифр в конце строки устроено очень просто: `\d+$`. Вероятно, вы уже видели подобные примеры в вашем учебнике по регулярным выражениям. На всякий случай ниже пример.

```
String s = "Пример №42";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
} else {
    System.out.println("Цифр в конце нет");
}
```

Обратный слеш в регулярке экранируется, поэтому их стало два.